# Many tap gesture in on view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have problem with tap gesture. My case is:
- A view with UITapGestureRecognizer to dismiss keyboard
- A label on view, which has 2 gesture. One `UITapGestureRecognizer` to open popup, and `UITapGestureRecognizer` (number of touches is 2) to quickly confirm popup.

But when I tap on label, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on view always receive the action. How can I forward action to `UILabel`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get taps on label, you need to enable user interaction for that label

To receive 2 taps you need to do following

In short `[tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dTap];` will do trick for you making single tap to wait for a while to check if double tap is to happen

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(doubleTapped:)];
dTap.delegate = self;
dTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
dTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[label addGestureRecognizer:dTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self 
                                   action:@selector(tapped:)];
tap.delegate = self;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dTap];
```

Answer (score 1):

// it Enables user interaction on you Lable, by default its NO, so you have to do it.

```
[lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons of my problem. Thanks.